# does not match type of accessor

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to build a storage class for my iPhone app. The storage class is for storing a list of food orders and each order has a food name and price. In the app, I want to store it in order into an 2 dimension array named **orders** when I press a button at my food menu.I am a Java user, and new to Objective-C. What I want to build is a storage class which is similar to java's ArrayList class, and  the Storage.m class holds the food name and price.

I have some code already, but it keeps shows up with this error: "Type of property 'orders' does not match type of accessor 'setOrder' " in my Storages.h class.

Storage.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Storage : NSObject{
    NSString *name;
    NSInteger *price;
}
@property (nonatomic)NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic)NSInteger *price;


@end
```

Storage.m

```
 #import "Storage.h"

 @implementation Storage


 @synthesize name;
 @synthesize price;


@end
```

Storages.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Storage.h"
@interface Storages : NSObject{
    Storage *order;
    NSMutableArray *orders;

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *orders; // error "Type of property 'orders' does not match type of accessor 'setOrder'"

-(void) setOrders:(Storage *)order;
-(NSMutableArray *) orders;
@end
```

Storages.m

```
#import "Storages.h"

@implementation Storages
@synthesize orders;

-(void) setOrders:(Storage *)oneOrder{  

    [orders addObject: oneOrder];
}
-(NSMutableArray *) orders;{
    return orders;
}
@end
```

Comment: Unsure why there's a 'java' tag on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a property called "orders", the function "setOrders" is overriding the setter method of that property.So to make it work you'll have to change the name of setOrders: function to something like addOrder:(Storage *)order.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a hanging "{" in your Storage.h. You need to end this.

Secondly, when you create a property it automatically establishes a setter and a getter for it. So in this case the setter is called `setOrders` You are overriding this (saying you want to implement it yourself). Change the name of `setOrders` in your code and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check outlet at xib file and linked procedure: they should have different names.